# How to zero down on load testing errors

Tags: nginx, timeout

Store run on Linode 8 GB RAM 4 cores, Magento 2, Nginx, PHP-FPM 7.2. I ran a test with 1000 clients for a minute and I see high error rate. Not much in magento or nginx error logs. Guidance please.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Do you use FPC or varnish?
How much time does the page loading take?
Any mysql error log?